# Unable to change working directory (to my local machine) in R while executing a code in AWS Console

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

Starting from home directory

```
getwd()
[1] "/home/manuel"
```

I was unable to change directory

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\yogesh\\Desktop\\Work\\R\\Defining Visits_Method_1")
```

and got the following error:

> Error in setwd("C:\Users\yogesh\Desktop\Work\R\Defining Visits_Method_1") : 
>         cannot change working directory

Comment: Are you working on a console which uses external server?

Comment: Yes , I am using external server